# <trajectory_msgs::JointTrajectory> Question

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

How do I declare positions in a trajectory_msgs::JointTrajectory variable?
I am trying to input a IK service reply into a JointTrajectory positions:

```
trajectory_msgs::JointTrajectory l_traj_goal;

for(unsigned int i=0; i < l_gpik_res.solution.joint_state.name.size(); i ++)
{
l_traj_goal.points.positions[i] = l_gpik_res.solution.joint_state.position[i];          
}
```

but I get a compiling error:

```
error: ‘trajectory_msgs::JointTrajectory_<std::allocator<void> >::_points_type’ has no member named ‘positions’
```

Does anyone know what's going on here? I think this is a small coding error but my C++ skills are lacking

Kind Regards,
Martin

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56029/%3Ctrajectory_msgs::jointtrajectory%3E-question/) by [MartinW](https://answers.ros.org/users/2868/martinw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 464 on 2013-02-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Points is an array, you need to select an element in the array:

```
l_traj_goal.points[0].positions[i] = ...
```

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2013-02-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MartinW](https://answers.ros.org/users/2868/martinw/) on 2013-02-25**:
Hey Fergs, thanks for the reply. It compiles now but I get a segmentation fault when I run the program. Any suggestions how to fix that?   (FIXED: I had to resize the elements in the array first)